# Stop AnimatorSet of ObjectAnimators in Android

Tags: android, animation, reset, objectanimator

Im trying to stop the animation of an `ImageView` when a button is clicked. The animation I am using is an `AnimatorSet` consisting of 5 `ObjectAnimators`... The problem is that I can't figure how to stop and clear this animation from the `ImageView` when the button is clicked as `btn.clearAnimation()` obviously doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to call `animatorSet.cancel()` to cancel the animation. Here's an example that cancels the animation 5 seconds after it starts:

```
package com.example.myapp2;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);

        List<Animator> animations = new ArrayList<Animator>();

        animations.add(ObjectAnimator.ofInt(tv, "left", 100, 1000).setDuration(10000));
        animations.add(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv, "textSize", 10, 50).setDuration(10000));

        final AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(animations);
        animatorSet.start();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animatorSet.cancel();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40):

If you had `AnimatorSet` listeners added, make sure you remove the listeners before cancel.

```
animatorSet.removeAllListeners();
animatorSet.end();
animatorSet.cancel();
```

Comment: Thats actually a really important fact.

Comment: There is no need for `end()` as `cancel` will call it automatically.
There would be a difference if you removed the listeners after the `cancel` as you will receive `onAnimationCancel` first and afterwards `onAnimationEnd`