# Android Property Animation not stopping

Tags: java, android, animation

I am trying to create a blinking effect dynamically for a CardView in android. This is the code i am using for creating the animator

```
stove1Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(stove1CardView, "backgroundColor", Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW,
            Color.WHITE);
stove1Animator.setDuration(1500);
stove1Animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
stove1Animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
stove1Animator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

and when ever i need i will start the animation with start() call. I am facing problem while stopping the blinking effect. The animation listeners are not getting called so i am trying to change the color in postHandler(). This is the code for cancelling the animation and setting a background color it is not working.

```
if (stove1Animator.isRunning()) {
     stove1Animator.cancel();
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

             setColor("S1",helper.getStringValueForPref("S1_COLOR"));
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
```

Comment: What is wrong with this question? I hope i have explained it clearly

Answer (score 0):

Use this to clear Animation

```
stove1Animator.clearAnimation()
```

**Solution 2:**

```
if (stove1Animator.isRunning()) {

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

             setColor("S1",helper.getStringValueForPref("S1_COLOR"));
             stove1Animator.removeAllListeners();
             stove1Animator.end();
             stove1Animator.cancel();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
```

Comment: stove1Animator is ObjectAnimator it is not view. It is not having clearAnimation() method. By the way if we start the animation using startAnimation clearAnimation will work. Thanks

Comment: @athersajjad Please post some more code to understand better..how you are setting ObjectAnimator into your view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493287/stop-animatorset-of-objectanimators-in-android please check this link as well

Comment: stove1Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(stove1CardView, "backgroundColor", Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW,
            Color.WHITE);
i am passing the stove1CardView reference when creating the stove1Animator. This is how i am setting it in code

Comment: @athersajjad got it.., check this https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.animation.ObjectAnimator&method=cancel